# Como posso repetir o cabeçalho pagina com jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

Estou a imprimir uma tabela com o jsPDF + AutoTable e quero que a secção de filtros da pagina seja sempre impressa no cabeçalho de cada pagina. Como o exemplo abaixo só é impresso na 1 pagina...ideias?

```
function printHTML() {  
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("table-content"));

doc.setFontSize(13);
doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.text('header1' , 20, 40);

doc.setFontSize(9);
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text('header2', 20, 52);

doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);

doc.save("table.pdf");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso tens de criar uma função com o que queres imprimir da tua pagina. Depois é passar a função ao plugin do AutoTable.

Isto deve dar.

```
Function printHTML() {

var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("table-content"));

var header = function() {

var header1 = document.getElementById("header1").innerHTML;
var header2 = document.getElementById("header2").innerHTML;

doc.setFontSize(13);
doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.text(header1 , 20, 40);

doc.setFontSize(9);
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(header2, 20, 52);

doc.setDrawColor(255,255,255,255);
doc.setLineWidth(2);
doc.line(20, 56, 555, 56); 
};

var options = {
theme: "plain", 
beforePageContent: header,

};

doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);
doc.save("table.pdf");
}
```